# Instancing GLB with multiple nodes and materials using REACT THREE FIBER/ DREI

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am using house from a GLB file in my project. as it is increasing in results in dropping frames and more draw calls. I want to draw it using  from react three drei. My nodes and materials look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7botL.png)

i am expecting to reduce the amount to calls and make is work flawlessly